what formula used in color counting in excel?
My boss gives me a task to conduct an inventory on a motor shop. After we performed the actual counting of products, we make a data entry. In the report we use a color assignment. After I finish the report, it needs to have a summary on the number of colors assigned on the item status.

If I have correctly understood what you mean, I'd use the filter and SUBTOTAL function.
Say you have a range of color (R2:R7). First, you apply a filter (from the Data tab) on the range and then you click on the dropdown and select Filter by color and choose a color. Then, in another cell outside of the range, you enter the following:
=SUBTOTAL(103; R2:R7)
103 indicates the visible cells. So you're calculating the number of visible cells that are filtered by color.
